# Pass variable from .h to .cpp

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I am trying to take the text input from the "Form1"(form.h) and pass it to the .cpp file(form.cpp).
**In form.h**

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
...
#pragma endregion
public: String^ username;
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
username = textBox1->Text;
//i want this variable in the .cpp file
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Please separate your example into the .cpp and .h files. Is this really C++? If so, usually the cpp file is compiled, and the header is included into it with the `#include` directive. From the syntax I believe this is something a bit more exotic, or a different language. It always helps to ask in more general ways, through small examples, which is guaranteed to be "standard" C++ syntax without any extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've created a class, and are assigning a value to a member variable, it's already going to be in your `.cpp` file, and can be referenced as long as you remember to `#include "form.h"` in it.

Note that this isn't necessarily the best practice, though.  It's often considered prudent to put all implementation details in your `.cpp` file - in part because it helps avoid confusing situations like these.